# How to display correct characters in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The collation of my database is `Chinese_PRC_CI_AI_WS`.

I execute the following command :

`SELECT info_project_name FROM db where info_project_name= '中駿•東投•雍景府'`

The result is : `中駿?東投?雍景府`

[image]

How to display the correct result?

Comment: How to display? Where?

Comment: please enhance question with expected result

Answer (score 0):

No,it can't do it.

`•` bytes are `e2 80 a2` and length is `3bytes`/one word,but varchar is `2bytes`/ one word. so when system insert `•` it only save `e2 80` not `e2 80 a2`.

you should use `nvarchar` type for info_project_name not `varchar` at first time.

example :

```
select '中駿•東投•雍景府' collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AI_WS --result : 中駿?東投?雍景府
select N'中駿•東投•雍景府' collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AI_WS ---result : 中駿•東投•雍景府
```

and why you colud get data by below sql

```
SELECT info_project_name FROM db where info_project_name= '中駿•東投•雍景府'
```

because it will be converted to

```
SELECT info_project_name FROM db where info_project_name= '中駿?東投?雍景府'
```